# Matlab evaluating and manipulating functions

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble evaluating functions.  I don't know how to manipulate the function then evaluate it at a number.  This is an example.  I want to take high order derivatives and evaluate each one at a number.
ie:

```
f(x)=x^3  

f'(x)=3x^2

f''(x)=6x

f(2)=8

f'(2)=12

f''(2)=12
```

I can write a function to output the derivatives but I don't know how to take them and evaluate them at a specific number.

Comment: Could you give an example input and what you would expect as result? It is not 100% clear to me.

Comment: derive(x^3,3,2) is the input.  The result should be [6 12 12]. Where derive is the name of the matlab function, x^3 is the equation, 3 is the number of derivatives and 2 is the number that is evluated.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic differentiation in MATLAB requires the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/), which may or may not be included in your MATLAB installation. If it is, you can use

```
syms x
```

To declare `x` as a symbolic variable and to define/manipulate functions of it. In this case you'd use

```
syms x;
f = x^3;
derivatives = [f diff(f) diff(f,2)];

derivatives =

     [ x^3, 3*x^2, 6*x]
```

Evaluating these functions at `x=2` can be done using

```
subs(derivatives, x, 2)

ans =

     8    12    12
```

You could also define `derivatives` using a loop if you want to be able to vary the number of derivatives you include.